# Execute Julia file from Python script

Tags: python, pandas, aws-lambda, julia

I'm trying to develop a Python script to deploy on AWS Lambda that will handle an invocation, prep data, and then pass that data input into a Julia script for processing (I am looking at Julia to speed up execution time compared to Pandas).  I have been working with the PyJulia library locally to try and get a simple test example but running into issues.  What are the issues with this set-up?

Here is the simple Python code:

```
python_handler.py

from julia import core.Julia

x = Julia()
print(x.eval("julia_script.jl"))
```

Here is the Julia script to be called:

```
julia_script.jl

for i in 1:10
    println(i)
end
```

From running 'python python_handler.py" I am expecting the julia_script.jl file to run printing 1-10 in the console but I keep getting errors.

Here's the repo importing from: 
https://github.com/JuliaPy/pyjulia/blob/master/src/julia/core.py

Is this even possible with Python and Julia, and if so, am I calling it the right way.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you mean to do x.eval('include("julia_script.jl")')

eval behaves basically like the REPL

Comment: That makes sense but I'm getting an error when trying to instantiate the Julia() object as x - looks like it is related to running on Anaconda Python; does PyJulia not conform with Anaconda:   File "C:\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found